# performance graphs with robotframework and jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins, robotframework

I have some performance tests that are executed by Jenkins using robotframework.  Each time it they are run, they generate a particular performance rate.

Is there a common jenkins plugin that can be used with robotframework that can be used to display historical performance graphs in Jenkins?

If for example there was a module to create JMeter XML format, I think I could use the Performance Plugin.  I presume others have done something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

You are right on point. [Performance plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) will show jmeter results in a nice, [graphical](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/42468533/shot_1.jpg?version=2&modificationDate=1278891097000) way. This performance plugin is a open source plugin and it has junit and jmeter parser implemented in it.